# Default validators in Symfony 2

Tags: validation, symfony

Is there a way to take a security by default approach to form and entity validation in Symfony? That is, if you do not define certain validators manually, apply a set of restrictive defaults? (For example, if you have a text field, and you do not specify the maximum length, automatically apply a maxlength of 32.)

Answer (score 0):

```
there is no defalut validation in symfony while you can do with annonation 
like 
 * @ORM\Column(name="height", type="decimal", nullable=true)
```